# Flask: Get URLs for each View class in module

Tags: python, url, flask, introspection

I'm trying to build a list of all urls and their respective View or MethodView classes. Each View may have 2 or more urls. I'm not sure whether to do this by starting at the class end, or the url map. My problem with starting with the class is that url_for only returns one url and the endpoint name could possibly be different to the class/method name. This is for building api documentation which seems to be keyed to the url (for end users).

Example:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class Bar(View):

    def dispatch_request(self):
        pass
app.add_url_rule('/short/', view_func=Bar.as_view('bar'))
app.add_url_rule('/short/<bar>/', view_func=Bar.as_view('bar'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The aim here is to be able to perform introspection on the module and get back a list Views all urls that are redirected to that View class or function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if something like:

```
rules = app.url_map._rules
for rule in rules:
    print rule.endpoint, rule, rule.defaults
```

Would get you the information you need.   You can read up more on it [in the Werkzeug documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule).

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to use something like this. You can bind a view to multiple URLs.

```
@app.route('/short/')
@app.route('/short/<bar>')
def dispatch_request(bar=None):
    pass
```

Comment: Sorry, my question must not have been very clear. I'm trying to do some introspection on a module and get back a list of [urls] => views/view functions.